# Django CORS ORIGIN WHITELIST and ALLOWED_HOST not filtering anything

Tags: python, django, reactjs, cors, axios

I'm trying to deploy a Django application (to make REST Apis ) and a React application (who use my Apis ) on the same `VPS`.
I'm setting up `CORS` for Django, and i still can use my API with postman as i shouldn't since i only allow my `VPS IP and localhost`.

I've tried first with 
`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["\*"]` and `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`
and everything went like it should, i could use my API from anywhere
but now when i replace `"\*"` with my `allowed hosts` and set cors origin allow all at `False` it's like nothing changed.
I tried to `remove/set http` from both `allowed hosts` and whitelist but it changed nothing.

```py
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ["MYIP","127.0.0.1"]
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["MYIP"]
```

I use python 3.6, django 2.2 and react 16.8.
Thank for helping

Comment: Have you set `DEBUG` to false?

Comment: CORS are headers meant for browsers. They protect users of web browsers. CORS isn't meant to protect your API from unwanted access. You need to use other methods for that.

Comment: Test your CORS headers like this: Embed a script calling your API on another website (e.g. give your localhost another name on your machine and open it there). Then try running the script. You'll see your script fetching the OPTIONS from your site and then an error in your browser. But you'll never see that in postman or curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Postman or curl (on any other direct HTTP requesting method) to test CORS. CORS is meant to tell **web browsers** (and only web browsers) which resources they should allow access to from within a web page.

The idea is to prevent someone with malicious-site.com that entices users to visit that site to fetch resources from your server (e.g. an iframe) so that the user *thinks* they're on your site when they actually aren't.

So you can only test it by running a script that fetches data from your API in webpage on a different domain (from within a browser). Test your CORS headers like this: Embed a script calling your API on another website (e.g. give your localhost another name on your machine and open it there). Then try running the script. You'll see your script fetching the OPTIONS from your site and then an error in your browser.

CORS is not meant for your website to prevent access entirely. Any machine using curl (or postman) will still be able to access your API.

Comment: It make more sense thank ! So in order to protect my API, is a token auth(with lifetime) enough ?